# ¿Como cargar todas las imágenes de la carpeta /drawable?

Tags: android

tengo alrededor de 100 imágenes drawable en android, quiero que se muestren aleatoria mente, pero no encuentro forma de cargar todas las imágenes de la carpeta drawable.

Alguna pista?, gracias

Comment: Si el uso que le querés dar a la imágenes se acerca más a tener un directorio con archivos, fijate si no te conviene más ponerlos en /assets en lugar de de /res/drawable. En assets los podes tratar como archivos en un filesystem.

Comment: Tienes algún patrón definido en el nombre o solo deseas cargar todas? Agrega mas información Jhon!

Answer (score 1):

se me ocurre algo como esto declara la lista de tus imágenes

```
public static final int[] typeIcon = {R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4 ..... R.drawable.image100};
```

y posteriormente recorre la lista en donde las quieres mostrar

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas obtener las imágenes de la carpeta `/drawable` y estas tienen un nombre definido, puedes realizarlo de esta manera usando [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Suponiendo que tus imágenes son 100 y tienen la siguiente nomenclatura:

> imagen1, imagen2, imagen3.........

puedes usar este método:

```
 private Drawable obtieneImagen(){ 
     Random r = new Random();
     int randomNumber = r.nextInt(100);//100 posibles imagenes.

       return = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                      .getIdentifier("imagen"+randomNumber, "drawable", getPackageName()));

 }
```